# When i add the "ItemSend" Event handler in my add-ins manifest.xml thrown error while installing the add-ins

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, office365api

In outlook add-ins try to add the ItemSend Event handling trigger in the manifest file ,but when i try to install manifest.xml not installing some error thrown

How to add the item send Event handler on my outlook add-ins

How to trigger this when click the save button , how to trigger the event on my commands.js file

Note : my add-ins developed by using javascript

Any thought about that please share me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure the right requirement set is specified in the manifest file. You must specify at least the 1.8 set for the `ItemSend` event because the `on-send` feature was officially released in requirement set 1.8. Read more about requirement sets in the [Requirements for running Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins) article.

In the manifest file, you typically need to include the function file and function name that should be called on the `ItemSend` event. The operation runs synchronously.

```
<Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this case, the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
```

The on-send API requires `VersionOverrides v1_1`. The following XML markup shows you how to add the `VersionOverrides` node in your manifest.

```
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
     <!-- On-send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
     <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
         ...
     </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Read more about that in the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) article.

You may also find the [Outlook-Add-in-On-Send](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) sample add-in on GitHub.